# Destroy DialogFragment on onCreateDialog()

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a dialog fragment that initializes Google plus views, sometimes those views fail so I'd like to kill the dialog at that point, before it's displayed to the user.

How can I end the dialog creation process? returning null from onCreateDialog which returns a Dialog object crushes the program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you'd like to dismiss DialogFragment within onCreateDialog you can do the following:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setShowsDialog(false);
    dismiss();
    return null;
}
```

No need to override onActivityCreated().

Comment: I would suggest returning a new Dialog() instead of null, since I had issues with NPEs on some systems. but all in all, yep, that is also a solution.

Comment: You can't return null as the result has to be non null: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment?hl=en#onCreateDialog(android.os.Bundle) .  Also, using this even with returning a non-null dialog, it still shows a transparent layer for me. This worked for me instead : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69141205/878126

Answer (score 3):

Solved it using the `onActivityCreated()` Fragment callback which is called after `OnCreateDialog()`. I return a valid Dialog from `onCreateDialog()` but flag with `dismiss` that the dialog should be dismissed.

```
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if(dismiss) {
        this.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: I managed to do this by calling dismiss() in onCreateDialog() itself.

Comment: Works, but deprecated: `use onViewCreated(View, Bundle) for code touching the Fragment's view and onCreate(Bundle) for other initialization. To get a callback specifically when a Fragment activity's Activity.onCreate(Bundle) is called, register a androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver on the Activity's Lifecycle in onAttach(Context), removing it when it receives the Lifecycle.State.CREATED callback.` . https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle) . I've created a more updated answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69141205/878126

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are a bit outdated and one didn't work for me (wrote there my comments about it), so here's what I think is updated and working:

On the `onCreateDialog` callback, have your logic of when it succeeds. If failed, return some default dialog (won't be used anyway) while adding to the lifecycle's onStart callback to dismiss the DialogFragment (use `dismiss` or `dismissAllowingStateLoss`):

```
fun Lifecycle.runOnStarted(runnable: () -> Unit) {
    addObserver(object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
        override fun onStart(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
            super.onStart(owner)
            runnable.invoke()
        }
    })
}
```

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    //create the builder of the dialog, and then check if need to dismiss
    if (needToDismiss) {
        lifecycle.runOnStarted{
            dismissAllowingStateLoss()
        }
        return builder.create()
    }
```

Alternative, using kotlin coroutines and without using the helper function I've made:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    //create the builder of the dialog, and then check if need to dismiss
    if (needToDismiss) {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            whenStarted {
                dismissAllowingStateLoss()
            }
        }
        return builder.create()
    }
```

Or you can use this helper function that uses kotlin coroutines to make it a bit shorter:

```
fun LifecycleOwner.runOnStarted(runnable: () -> Unit) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        whenStarted{
            runnable.invoke()
        }
    }
}
```

The usage would be as short as before:

```
runOnStarted{
    dismissAllowingStateLoss()
}
```

Note that I use onStart callback instead of onCreate. The reason is that for some cases, onStart works, while onCreate won't.